# Not able to install internet explorer!

Tags: software-installation, browser

I followed [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingInternetExplorer) for installing Internet explorer.

A GUI opens when I run the following command:

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/ies4linux-2.99.0.1$ pwd
/home/ravbholua/ies4linux-2.99.0.1
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/ies4linux-2.99.0.1$ ./ies4linux
IEs4Linux 2 is developed to be used with recent Wine versions (0.9.x). It seems that you are using an old version. It's recommended that you update your wine to the latest version (Go to: winehq.com).
```

Please note the message after running the above command. But I don't think mine is old version as mentioned above. Please see below to know my version:

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/ies4linux-2.99.0.1$ wine --version
wine-1.7.4
```

Mine is latest version.
Now in the GUI, I select IE6 to install. But it fails to install and I get the below error:

```
An error ocurred when downloading. Please run IEs4Linux again. Corrupted file: ie6/EN-US/VGX.CAB
```

Please say how to then install IE?

Comment: Why you are installing IE ?

Comment: @RahulPatil it is very useful when developing web pages. That way, you can check if it works on IE easily.

Comment: hmm, then he need to use cross browser testing tool... isn't it ?

Comment: @RahulPatil currently I have the need for it because I want to make fund transfer from my Kotak Mahindra Bank via IMPS. I couldn't do that via other browser and the customer care told that it would work on IE. So, I am compelled to install that. (BTW I am also from Mumbai)

Comment: Consider Microsoft's [official virtual machines with Windows + IE](http://www.modern.ie/virtualization-tools)

Comment: @ignis I don't think I can consider as my RAM is 1GB. Ubuntu needs 1GB for proper running. If I install virtual machine, then it would be very slow and i can't work.

Comment: In some cases you can use a plugin to your browser that will change your browser's useragent so that it "fools" the website into thinking your using browserX when using browserY. This has worked for me in the past on certain sites. Here's one such browser for Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/

Comment: @slm you are amazing! It has worked for the bank website also. I pretended my mozilla to be IE8 and the operation what I wanted to perform on the bank site was successful. This operation in the bank site was pending since nearly 2 months and now it succeeded. Great information you have provided which I never thought. Absolutely amazing!!! Thank you very much slm

Comment: @Ravi - I've written up the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases you can use a plugin to your browser that will change your browser's useragent so that it "fools" the website into thinking your using browserX when using browserY. This has worked for me in the past on certain sites. Here's one such plugin for Firefox, called [user-agent-switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/), for example.

#### Background

When a browser connects to a website, it sends a strings such as this identifying itself using this string, "user agent".

> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36

The details of the above are as follows:

[image: ss of user agent info]

The above is Chrome's string, from a Linux system. You can see what yours is by navigating to this website, [User Agent String.Com](http://www.useragentstring.com/).

By using a plugin such as the one mentioned above, you can manipulate your browser's "user agent" to be anything you want. In this case you're changing it to match a "user agent" string for another browser, in this case say Internet Explorer (IE).

Something like this:

> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)

Comment: All that does is make the server think the browser is IE but, unless the server does something different with that info, Chrome will still behave like Chrome. He wants to use or emulate IE which can't be done without Windows.

Comment: @Rob - read the comments under the Q. This is what worked for him and I'm writing it up as an answer! What you're saying is correct, but this is an alternative, and in this case is what ultimately worked for the OP.

Comment: You are right. I had assumed he was doing this for technical reasons, like web site testing, and not personal.

Comment: @Rob - I originally thought the same as you and even wrote up an answer around that. Only later yesterday did we find out that he was actually trying to access a bank with IE, so now the Q is a bit misleading since the more typical use case is what you (and I) thought (IMO).

Answer (score 1):

> Please note the message after running the above command. But I don't think mine is old version as mentioned above.

I wonder if that has something to do with [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEs4Linux#Technical_notes).

> Version 2.99.0.1 does not work out-of-the-box on newer Wine and KDE
>   versions. The solution is to create a symlink with
>
> ```
> sudo ln -sv /usr/bin/winecfg /usr/bin/wineprefixcreate
> ```
>
> and then run
>   ./ies4linux with the --no-gui command line option.

And please please tell me you are doing this just to test web-dev on IE6.  That browser is a *nightmare*. http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: Thanks, let me check how it works what you told. I am doing this for the reason I mentioned in the comment of my question. I would like to add that the reason I am installing IE6 is that I got that option while installing. There was no option for higher versions.

Comment: amazing! Yes it worked for me (with 1 error that I would point later). But the purpose I installed IE6 didn't get solved. As I had told in other comment that I need to do some operation in a bank site. So, for that, I think I need to install newer IEs. But earlier, while installing it asked me "type ie6 to install ...". There was no option for installing IE8. How to install IE8? May I type IE8 when it asks me to type ie6!!

Answer (score 1):

ies4linux is ancient. While you might get it working with current versions of Wine, you'd be better off by not bothering with installing IE in Wine: Microsoft provides [VMs](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads) with Windows + IE pre-installed.

*Here's the [news blurb about the release of modern.ie](http://readwrite.com/2013/01/31/microsoft-launches-modernie-to-boost-web-site-compatibility#awesm=~oluj106mhvMhdR) on 01/31/2013*

> Microsoft on Thursday launched Modern.ie, a set of free tools and services designed to facilitate writing better code across a variety of operating systems, browsers, and devices. But it's also an effort to keep developers coding for the PC and Windows, with an emphasis on Internet Explorer.

Comment: +1 - good tip, never heard of these but will be using them in the future, thanks Renan!